# Host Serial Port forward to Azure VM Client

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I am writing a barcode program using a VM in Azure. The software on my local machine emulates a serial port using a USB port.

Is there a way to forward data from, for example, comm port 3, to the azure VM.

******* edited 3/21/19 - in response to my realization and SumanthMarigowda-MSFT

[image]

but in the Azure VM I am only seeing com1 and com2:

[image]

Gina

Comment: I'm a dope. I just realized that through RDP advanced settings I can forward ports. I will give that a try.

Comment: post updated above. RDP allows serial ports but I don't see com3

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to: Virtual machine serial console for [Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/serial-console-windows) or [Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/serial-console-linux)

If you need your local usb to work[image]

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.